# Difference between $.ajax(); and $.ajaxSetup();

Tags: jquery, ajax

What is the difference between `$.ajax();` and `$.ajaxSetup();` in jQuery as in:

```
$.ajax({
    cache:false
});
```

and

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache:true
});
```

Also, which one is best option?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The following will prevent **all** future AJAX requests from being cached, regardless of which jQuery method you use ($.get, $.ajax, etc.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

you should use $.ajax, which will allow you to turn caching off **for that** instance:

```
$.ajax({url: "myurl", success: myCallback, cache: false});
```

Comment: Note: You don't have to wait until the `ready` event to change the setup. Actually that would be too late if there are AJAX calls in inline scripts.

Answer (score 16):

`ajaxSetup` sets default values to be valid for all ajax requests. After this you don't have to do the same setting in `$.ajax`

All settings in `$.ajax` will be valid only for that ajax call.

Answer (score 5):

The first one disables cache on a per request basis, the second one sets it up to be disabled globally by default for all AJAX functions.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid caching, one option is to give different URL for the same resource or data. To generate different URL, you can add a random query string to the end of the URL.  This technique works for JQuery, Angular or other type ajax requests.

```
myURL = myURL +"?random="+new Date().getTime();
```

JQuery uses the similar technique via  `$.ajax({cache:false});` and `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});`

`$.ajax({cache:false})` applies the technique on which it is included,  `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});`  applies the technique for all AJAX functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, which one is best option?

According to [jQuery api documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/), using `$.ajaxSetup()` is not recommended:

> Note: The settings specified here will affect all calls to `$.ajax` or Ajax-based derivatives such as `$.get()`. This can cause undesirable behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting the normal default settings. For that reason *we strongly recommend against using this API*. Instead, set the options explicitly in the call or define a simple plugin to do so.