# Modifications on files are not displayed until application restart (File API)

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, phonegap-plugins, fileapi

I am building a basic Ios application using PhoneGap and the [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html) to download and update XML files.

The download part is done with Ajax calls and the update is done with FileEntry objects.

Here what it looks like :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://site/folder/GetFluxXmlServlet",
        dataType: "text",

        beforeSend: function () {
            Results.innerHTML = 'Loading...<br>';
        },

        success: function (MAJ) {

            var content = MAJ;

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", checkIfFileExists, false);

            function checkIfFileExists() {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
                    fileSystem.root.getFile("global.xml", { create: false }, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
                }, getFSFail);
            }

            function fileExists(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(truncateFile, fileDoesNotExist);
            }

            function truncateFile(writer) {
                writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
                    console.log("Writer" + evt.code);
                    writer.seek(0);
                    writer.onwriteend = function (evt) {
                        console.log("Changed" + evt.code);
                    };
                    writer.write(content);
                };
                writer.truncate(0);
            }

            function fileDoesNotExist() {

                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

                function onDeviceReady() {
                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);
                }

                function onSuccess(fileSystem) {

                    var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root;

                    directoryEntry.getFile("global.xml", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                            writer.write(content);
                        }, function (e) {
                            console.log("Error :" + e.code);
                        });
                    }, function (e) {
                        console.log("Error :" + e.code);
                    });
                }

                function onError(evt) {
                    console.log("Error :" + evt.code);
                }
            }

            function getFSFail(evt) {
                console.log(evt.target.error.code);
            }
        },

        complete: function () {
            Results.innerHTML = 'Success';
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    })
```

1. Ajax call
2. Retrieve the data
3. If the file exists we truncate it and write the new data
4. If the file doesn't exist, we create it and write the data
5. Reload the page

All this works fine, but when modifications are made to the file (server side) and I click on my update button **I don't get the changes until the application is restarted.**

I tried :

- Removing the file and recreating it
- I checked the Metadata
- I changed the file path
- Etc...

To conclude, the file created is called by other Ajax method within a global variable defined like this:

```
window.global = fileEntry.toURL();
```

Can this influence the recuperation of new data, or is there a better way for updating a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extrapolating my research, I found out that Ajax request are being [cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750447/difference-between-ajaxcachefalse-and-ajaxsetupcachefalse-in-jqu) so I simply added :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

at the beginning of my Javascript file.

For more informations :
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxsetup.asp