# ASP.NET MVC caching and IoS safari

Tags: ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, safari

I have a Controller like

```
[OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Any, VaryByParam = "category", Duration = 60)]
    public ActionResult Search(string keywords, string location, string category)
    {
```

//... return View etc..
}

and ajax request on this view

```
function refreshPager(pageNum, nextOper) {
    $.ajax({
        url: String.format("/Adv/GetPagesData?currentPage={0}&SortBy={1}&keywords={2}&location={3}&country={4}&category={5}&minPrice={6}&maxPrice={7}&type={8}&condition={9}", pageNum, $("#SortBy option:selected").text(), $("#keywords").val(), $("#id-location").val(), $("#Country option:selected").val(), $("#search-category option:selected").val(), $("#minPrice").val(), $("#maxPrice").val(), $("#ajaxTabs li[class='active']").attr("id"), $("#condition option:selected").val()),
        method: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: { query: 'test' },
        success: function (pdata) {
            pagedata = pdata;
            maxPages = pdata.length;
            if (pageNum < 1) pageNum = 1;
            if (pageNum > maxPages) pageNum = maxPages;
            currentPage = pageNum;
            ko.mapping.fromJS(pagedata, {}, viewModel.PagedItems);
            $(".pageItem").removeClass("selectedItem");
            $(".pageItem:eq(" + pageNum + ")").addClass("selectedItem");

        }
    }).fail(function () { alert('Ошибка получения данных, попробуйте еще раз') }).success(function () {
        count = 0;
        $('.pager-btn').each(function (index, el) {

            if (el.innerHTML == pageNum) {
                $(el.parentNode).addClass("active");
                count++;
            }
        });
        if (count == 0) {
            $('#NotFound').show();
        } else {
            $('#NotFound').hide();
        }
        nextOper(currentPage);
    });
}
```

thats fine works in all Windows browsers but fails in IoS Safari.
When caching attribute is off then it's ok in Safari too.
May be someone got that problem too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will prevent all future AJAX requests from being cached, regardless of which jQuery method you use ($.get, $.ajax, etc.)

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Reference Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7750483/3041974