# When not to cache AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-caching

I understand that AJAX caching optimizes or improves performance regarding network latency and data charges, but when (or what) should be the circumstance/s that would make caching a bad choice? Or specifically, using jQuery, when to use `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false})`?

Comment: It seems look like Duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750447/difference-between-ajaxcachefalse-and-ajaxsetupcachefalse-in-jqu

Comment: Nope. Try reading that question and the answers. :)

Comment: When you've got data updated server side at the same location ?

Comment: @Kaiido Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Lets take the example of an image from a webcam, updated every x minutes, you don't want to get it cached, because after x minutes it won't be the same image anymore.

Comment: @Kaiido Ah so you mean that it is only a waste of resources when you cache it?

Comment: No, I mean sometimes (pretty rare), you want a request to always return a new response from the server. It's never a waste of resources to cache it.

Comment: @Kaiido So if the requested file/resource is dynamic, and you use caching, then you will only get the same response every time?

Answer (score 2):

One reason to not cache is if you need to be sure to work on non-outdated data.

In the expiration caching model (max-age, expires etc.) you can totally end up with stale data served from caches if not done correctly.

In the validation caching model (based on ETags, Last-Modified) you end up with conditional requests that involve the server but probably save bandwidth if the response in the cache is still current.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, another reason not to cache is to prevent data to be stored unnecessarily in the client. Some types of data change a lot. Storing them can use up storage space and computational resources, which may be particularly important in a mobile device. Keeping the data can also pose a potential security risk, when a shared computer is used for instance.